# AngularJs Convert string datetime to datetime object

Tags: angularjs

I need to convert "10-28-2016 10:27:14 AM" string datetime to datetime Fri Oct 28 2016 12:04:16 in angularJs 
Pls Help

Comment: When you ask for help, please provide a context instead of how do I do A / B.

Comment: Checkout http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

view

```
<p>{{'10-28-2016 10:27:14 AM' | filter}}</p>
```

filter and controller

```
angular
    .module('myApp',[])
    .run(function($rootScope){
        $rootScope.title = 'myTest Page';
    })
    .controller('testController', ['$scope', function($scope){

    }]).filter('filter', function($filter) {

return function(input) {

var date = new Date(input);
return($filter('date')(date, 'EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss') );
  }
});
```

Comment: how can it setting this in global.

Comment: use it as a directive or filter

Comment: any sample from you

Comment: This is just a formatting in view.And not creating date object

Comment: if you want to create date object from string `'10-28-2016 10:27:14 AM'` you need to use `var dateObj = new Date('10-28-2016 10:27:14 AM');`

Answer (score 1):

Best bet is to read through MDN [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) documentation. Here is an example:

```js
const date = new Date('10-28-2016 10:27:14 AM')

console.info(date.toDateString())
console.info(date.toTimeString())
console.info(date.toUTCString())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default `javascript` method `new Date("10-28-2016 10:27:14 AM")` to generate it

Answer (score 0):

The best way should be to convert string-date to Date object, using moment.js or natively, where string first occurs (you are either getting it via API or from user's input).
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

And then just use angular's built-in date filter to display formatted value as you like, for example:

```
{{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

When you are ready to send date back to the server, you should convert it to UTC string and persist it like that in the database, to avoid all the time zones issues.

```
date.toUTCString();
```

Where date is valid Date object, previously stored as such.